# Compiling tor in Solaris SPARC 10

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors, solaris, tor, setenv

I have a sun server with Solaris 10 SPARC installed.
I have successfully installed libevent as well as openssl using tarball source code. I am trying to compile tor-0.2.5.16 using gnu gmake. I have encountered the following problem on my solaris terminal as follows

```
CCLD    src/test/test
Undefined       first referenced
unsetenv        src/test/src_test_test-test-util.o
setenv          src/test/src_test_test-test-util.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to src/test/test
```

Where do I go from here?

Comment: You should implement setenv and unsetenv based on putenv and getenv.

Answer (score 1):

`setenv()` and `unsetenv()` are POSIX 6/SUSv3/XPG6 functions.  If you have an older installation of Solaris 10, it may predate POSIX 6 and may not have `setenv()` nor `unsetenv()`. `/usr/include/stdlib.h` will have something like this in it if your installation has `setenv()` and `unsetenv()`:

```
#if defined(__EXTENSIONS__) || \
    (!defined(_STRICT_STDC) && !defined(__XOPEN_OR_POSIX)) || \
    defined(_XPG6)
extern int posix_memalign(void **, size_t, size_t);
extern int posix_openpt(int);
extern int setenv(const char *, const char *, int);
extern int unsetenv(const char *);
#endif
```

Note that to use the functions, you have to have specific values `#define`'d.  Do not try to `#define` these directly.  Per [the `standards.5` man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5175/standards-5.html#REFMAN5standards-5) you have to `#define` or use the `-D` compiler option `_XOPEN_SOURCE=600`.  And you **must not** define `_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED` at all.  If `_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED` is defined along with `_XOPEN_SOURCE`, you will get SUS/XPG4v2 and not SUS3/XPG6.

Comment: Hi Andrew  . thanks for the quick reply. I have made a mistake. I am running Solaris SPARC 5.9 and not Solaris 10 SPARC. PLease ignore teh title to this thread. Based upon this update above. How will it impact the info you have just gave me?

Comment: @greenelephant Solaris 9 only supports up to SUSv2/XPG4v2.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification#Solaris

Comment: Are there any tarballs or features that can install/upgrade to POSIX 6/SUSv3/XPG6 functions in Solaris 9?

Comment: I have however tried to install tor source code into Solaris 01 SPARC and I get the following error

Comment: gcc: unrecognised option '-rdynamic'

Comment: symbol [[LARGE GAP]]   first referenced

Comment: __stack_chk_fail [[large gap]] /src/or/tor_main.o

Comment: __stack_chk_guard [[large gap]] /src/or/tor_main.o

Comment: ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors . No output written to /src/or/tor

Comment: collect2: ld: returned 1 exit status

Comment: What shall I do next Andrew Henle?

Comment: @greenelephant What source code are you trying to install?  The easiest thing to do depends on how many times the source you are trying to compile uses `setenv()` and `unsetenv()`.  If it uses those functions a lot, you should do like Lorinczy Zsigmond stated in his comment - implement them yourself using `putenv()` and `getenv()`.  You should be able to find examples rather easily.  If the code you're trying to compile only uses `setenv()`/`unsetenv()` a few times, rewrite that part of the code to use `putenv()` and `setenv()` to do the same thing.  Be wary of threading issues, too.

Comment: Hi andrew. I should really start a new thread. im no longer using Solaris 9 and am using Solaris 10 instead as this will resolve the unsetenv and setenv issues. I therefore am trying to install tor source code 0.2.5.16 into Solaris 10 SPARC. The errors I encounter this time are __stack_chk_fail and __stack_chk_guard when trying to compile /src/or/tor_main.o . I hope this clarifies my situation with you. ((I am now using Solaris 10 SPARC so I dont have to deal with the setenv and unsetenv issues I had before) . I shall await your response regarding the tor_main.o issue

Comment: @greenelephant Are you using gcc to compile?  You probably have a version mismatch somewhere, or the version on Solaris 10 is too old.  If you search for `__stack_chk_fail` there are a lot of questions and answers.  One of those is probably relevant.

Comment: Yes I am using gcc to attempt to compile tor-0.2.5.16 . this is the standard package that comes with Solaris 10 SPARC (ie SUNWgcc SUNWgccruntime)

Comment: I'll try OPENCSW packages for gcc and let you know how I get on :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried OPENCSW gcc-4.6.3, I didnt work either. That being said I have succeeded in compiling and installing tor-0.2.4.20 instead. You were right. It was an issue regarding the GCC compiler I was using (too old) so I had to use an older version of tor instead. Thanks for your help though. Much appreciated!!! I may need asistance in getting gcc-9.1.0 tarball installed though. Will start a new thread if I encounter problems. :) :)